# Hosting a WPF page located in a plugin DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, dll

I'm designing a WPF program that will use a DLL-plugin architecture. The host application is more "chrome" than content. It's in charge of providing a consistent look and feel, as well as providing some features common to all the plugins (Such as a "Check for updates" button).

However, my plan is that 3rd party developers will code the plugins. As such, they will need to add plugin specific functionality. I've designed the host application so that it allocates a tab page (or two, if the plugin requests it), and will allow the plugin to fill that tab page with its own buttons, listboxes, ect, which will then trigger the appropriate code in the plugin.

Kind of like MDI, except that the buttons will be hosted in the host application's tab page, but will trigger events in the plugin.

I need some help figuring out how to implement this design. What do I, as the host-programmer, need to do to support this (Such as loading the plugin and filling the tab page)? What will the plugin developers need to do to

- "Embed" their WPF in my tab page
- Catch events generated by their embedded controls
- Get this into a DLL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [WPF Add-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909794.aspx#WPFAddInModel) architecture. Here is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909887.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed this.

Answer (score 2):

Much of the boilerplate stuff needed to implement a plugin architecture can be found in the Managed Extensibility Framework:
http://mef.codeplex.com/

As for hosting buttons on the Host that will trigger events in the client page, you can achieve this by executing a specific command with the client page set as the Target. Here is an example of executing the 'Paste' command on a Page called "hostedWpfPageControl":

```
ApplicationCommands.Paste.Execute(null, this.hostedWpfPageControl);
```